# In case of High Trust Provider Hosted App; do they need to only run on SSL?

Tags: provider-hosted-app, ssl, sharepoint-on-prem, certificate

Is it necessary for the High Trust Provider Hosted App, running in on premise environment to have SSL configure?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended way to use the SSL for High trust provider hosted app but you can create without it.

You need to use SSL to run apps in your SharePoint web applications.you will of course need a wildcard SSL certificate for your app domain if you are using SSL for your SharePoint environment.  Which of course you should be, especially when implementing Apps since OAuth access tokens for Apps will be in plain text otherwise and could be replayed by a malicious user or code.if you plan to use apps that use data external to the SharePoint sites, you should use SSL for your apps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Waqas. 
Is there any MSDN document about the best practices for High trust app configuration which I can refer to.